# Create a ranklist for my discord.js Bot

Tags: javascript, sqlite, discord.js

I have a table named "scores" and want to filter the UserId and sort by their points. I want to create a ranklist command for my Discord Bot, but I don't know how to do this.

I though it is like this but it doesnt work:

```
const sql = require("sqlite");
sql.open("score.sqlite");
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    var index = 1;
    var msg = "-- Top 5 list --\n";
    sql.get("SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 5").then(rows => {
        for (index = 1; index < 6; index++) {
            if (rows[index] !== null) {
                msg += index + ". " + rows[index].userId + " - " + rows[index].points + "\n";
            }
        }
        console.log(msg);
    });
};
```

Can you guys help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific about *"it doesn't work"*.

Comment: There is no error. and in the console is also nothing.

Comment: You don't seem to be catching errors. Try adding an error handler to your `.get` and/or see if you get as far as your query at least.

Comment: I receive the following error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined"
But I don`t understand why.

Comment: Just look at what you get in your `rows`. `undefined` and `null` are different things in JavaScript, your null-guard `if` statement only works if there are explicit `null` values in the `rows` array.

You can simply check `if(rows[index])` to guarantee there is a truthy value.

Comment: Okay, I did it. Or how would you do it to rank this people by its points?

Comment: My table: http://prntscr.com/g2xk53 (Screenshot)

Comment: @DarthJDG Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databasegetsql-param--callback

> The signature of the callback is function(err, row) {}. If the result
>   set is empty, the second parameter is undefined, otherwise it is an
>   object containing the values for ***the first row***.

sql.get only returns a single row object (not a ***rows*** array of ***row*** objects). You need to use either sql.each or sql.all.

sql.all
https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseallsql-param--callback

sql.each
https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete

EDIT: it looks like you're trying to make a discord point system bot. There is a really good guide on all of this here.
https://anidiotsguide.gitbooks.io/discord-js-bot-guide/coding-guides/storing-data-in-an-sqlite-file.html